# Вывод денег из google play market

Tags: android, google-play

Помогите, пожалуйста, вывести деньги из play market. Заработала 100$, открыла в банке долларовый счет, в консоли разработчика ввела реквизиты. А как теперь сделать, чтоб они мне деньги на счет перевели? Куда и что нажимать? Можно как-то подробнее?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Answer (score 4):

Теперь вам надо просто подождать.

В какой-то момент у вас в <kbd>Merchant Center</kbd> в разделе <kbd>Выплаты</kbd>→<kbd>Транзакции</kbd> появится строка <kbd>Автоматический платеж: Банковский перевод на счет ...</kbd>

В крайнем случае вы можете связаться с саппортом гугла и спросить правильно ли вы ввели все данные для перевода.